# How to set CSRF token in Postman

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman, csrf, spring-security-rest

I am using Spring Boot 2 and Spring 5 in order to create an app that saves two entities: User and UserProfile. This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("userProfile")
public class UserProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @PostMapping(produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createUserProfile(@RequestBody @Valid UserProfileDTO userProfileDTO, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
//code 
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getUserProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
        //code
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, I get the authenticated user and I set that and save it or I fetch the data based on the authenticated user. My security configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

Now I want to test with Postman. The GET works fine, I add the form data in Postman and it authenticates and I can debug the get method. POST is always identified as 403 Forbidden. I don't want to disable CSRF or/and cors. How can I test my application, fetch the CSRF token and set it in Postman?

Comment: Do you see your CSRF Token in cookies after sending the first GET request?

Comment: I see the csrf token in the first login form

Comment: Did you try to send the CSRF Token in X-CSRFToken header?

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain the XSRF value from your login response (or wherever it is initially sent), store that in your environment, and add it to your POST headers.

I'm using Spring Security, so the XSRF value is returned as a `SET-COOKIE` header named `XSRF-TOKEN` which I'm saving as `csrftoken`
[image: Screenshot of Postman post-login code saving the token]

Then including in my POST as a header named `X-XSRF-TOKEN`

[image: Screenshot of setting the token in an outgoing header]

Your header values may be named something different, but this general approach should work.

Comment: How do you know the name of the cookie? Is there a list to check?

Comment: @azzurroverde - I'm not sure that there is a generic way to do this, but I looked through the response with developer tools for a "set-cookie" value that appeared relevant